# Is my drive good or going bad?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smartctl

I just ran SMART on my server's drives but I'm not *too* sure how to interpret it.

My results seem like the drive is doing fine, but I would like a second (or third) opinion, just to be safe.

Here are the results:

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   120   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       243846539
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1007
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   077   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       57855713
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       22900
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       521
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   052   045    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 28/37)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   048   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 15 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   035   014   000    Old_age   Always       -       243846539
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       14491219680816
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2006043213
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4019475959
```

Comment: Is that a Seagate drive?

Comment: Yes that is! Barracuda 7200.12. Did you recognize it from the Spin_Retry_Count "Pre-fail" labelling?

Comment: Your drive is perfectly fine. It will run for another hour or another ten years.